# Bug in jQuery's element creation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

$(document).ready(function(){
        var _new_li     = $('',     {
          'id':     'p',
          'text':   'CLICKME',
          click:    function(){
              alert('fired');
          },
          data:     {
              'somedata':  'somedata',
          }
        });

```
_new_li.appendTo($("#example"));
});
```

I receive an "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined**", when I try to click the element which I created like so.
But, if you switch click: and data: it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var _new_li     = $('<li/>',     {
      'id':     'p',
      'text':   'CLICKME',
      data:     {
          'somedata':  'somedata',
      },
      click:    function(){
          alert('fired');
      }                      
    });

_new_li.appendTo($("#example"));
});
```

any explanation for that behavior?

Kind Regards

--Andy

PS:

I posted a similar behavior earlier in the jQuery Core Development forum, Mr. Swedberg answered there:

> I'm pretty sure this is happening because you're setting data with an object, which         >(until 1.4.2) would overwrite the event object. Not sure which version of jQuery you're >using in your project, but it looked like the jsbin example was using 1.4. Try upgrading >to 1.4.2 and see if that helps.

But it seems like the problem still exists in 1.4.2

Comment: That *seems* to be the case. You might want to submit a ticket, or post a comment here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: is data defined in both cases?

Comment: I don't get an error, but I also don't get anything to happen when I click. When I switch them around, it does work. I'd log a bug.

Comment: @SB "data" is a property name, not a value; it's on the left side of the colon, in other words, so it's not interpreted as a reference to a variable.

Comment: I think SB must mean does `_new_li.data('somedata')` return `undefined`, or is the value being set.

Comment: @patrick, @SB - ah OK well if that's the question, then yes, my test page does successfully set "somedata".

Comment: This might have something to do with the fact that "data" is regarded as special by `$.attr` while none of the others are.

Comment: @Pointy, "data", "click" and "text" are all considered "special" -- i.e. the corresponding jQuery method is called for each of these. I think that this is a bug, jAndy, so I suggest reporting it.

Comment: @J-P look around line 1450 of the un-minified jQuery 1.4.2 source - there's a short list of property names it looks for; "data" is in the list, but "click" is not.

Comment: @Pointy, look at line 2604 :)

Comment: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6484

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post rewrited.

You shouldn't put that comma after last (and only) element in data.

After trying some stuff I got to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fun=function(){
          alert('fired');
      };
    var parms={
      'id':     'p',
      'text':   'CLICKME',     
      'click':fun,         
      'data':     {
          'somedata':  'somedata'
      }
      };
      console.log(parms);
    var _new_li = $('<li/>',parms);

_new_li.appendTo($("#example"));
});
```

Everything works fine until I click on the li element. Then I get `e is undefined (jquery line 55)`. Works well when click and data are swapped.

Still investigating

**AND FOUND IT**

jquery development version, line 1919

> var events = jQuery.data(this,
>   "events"), handlers = *events*[
>   event.type ];

*events* is undefined.

jquery overwrites events stored in data.

so this IS a bug. It should just extend.

*I've submited a bug report.*

Comment: "Try 'click' instead of click as it might be coliding with a variable." -- What? It's to the left of the colon and is therefore resolved as an identifier -- having a variable with the same name in the same scope makes no difference.

Comment: And also, jQuery does not change ANY native/host objects.

Comment: -1  1) there is no trailing comma, 2) 'click' should make absolutly no difference. see http://jsbin.com/akeyo/3/edit

Comment: @J-P Yes, but He might have used something ELSE
As for the click - it was when I couldn't reproduce

Comment: @jAndy there IS a comma here: `'somedata',`. I'm trying to help. Is that wrong?

Comment: removed the -1 after you edited your post. Well, I thought they fixed the 'overwrite' in 1.4.0.

Comment: where did you submit the bug report?

Comment: "jquery overwrites events stored in data." -- I'm having trouble finding where it does this. If this were the case then presumably `.click(fn).data({})` would also fail, but it doesn't...

Comment: I posted a similar behavior earlier in the jQuery Core Development forum, Mr. Swedberg answered there:

'm pretty sure this is happening because you're setting data with an object, which (until 1.4.2) would overwrite the event object. Not sure which version of jQuery you're using in your project, but it looked like the jsbin example was using 1.4. Try upgrading to 1.4.2 and see if that helps. 

But it seems like the problem still exists in 1.4.2

Comment: @jAndy posted http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6484, my tests were on latest jquery
@J-P Line I copied does jQuery.data(this, "events") and gets nothing. If putting data after event causes this to happen then it's rather obvious. (and it turns out to be a known problem)

Comment: @J-P And to be clear. `.click(fn).data({})` does not fail becouse it's after element is created and this little chain of Yours does different things than the example posted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

folks.. this is no bug.. what's happening is that you need to use the event data argument

```
.click( [ eventData ], handler(eventObject) )
```

eventDataA map of data that will be passed to the event handler.

to know why that's necessary you can review the discussion in the jquery documentation of .bind().. you may also want to review the concept of "closure" in javascript.. it provides the rationale behind this whole thing

this part is especially relevant (taken from http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

Passing Event Data

The optional eventData parameter is not commonly used. When provided, this argument allows us to pass additional information to the handler. One handy use of this parameter is to work around issues caused by closures. For example, suppose we have two event handlers that both refer to the same external variable:

```
var message = 'Spoon!';
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  alert(message);
});
message = 'Not in the face!';
$('#bar').bind('click', function() {
  alert(message);
});
```

Because the handlers are closures that both have message in their environment, both will display the message Not in the face! when triggered. The variable's value has changed. To sidestep this, we can pass the message in using eventData:

```
var message = 'Spoon!';
$('#foo').bind('click', {msg: message}, function(event) {
  alert(event.data.msg);
});
message = 'Not in the face!';
$('#bar').bind('click', {msg: message}, function(event) {
  alert(event.data.msg);
});
```

This time the variable is not referred to directly within the handlers; instead, the variable is passed in by value through eventData, which fixes the value at the time the event is bound. The first handler will now display Spoon! while the second will alert Not in the face!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying the source code slightly, so it would not randomly blow up here.

```
handle: function( event ) {
...

// tbn modified source
try {
   var events = jQuery.data(this, "events"), handlers = events[ event.type ];
} catch(e) {}
// tbn modified source
```

..then re-minified the source

I have not had any problems with this since (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I was running into a similar issue.  I was trying to bind events like mouseout, click, etc... to an new LI element.  I kept getting the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseout' of undefined'.  Turns out, you have to bind events like click, mouseout, etc... AFTER you've appended the element to the DOM.  Not before.  Rough example:

```
newLI = $('<li />');
$(document.body).append(newLI); // Correct
newLI.click(...);
newLI.mouseout(...);
```

instead of

```
newLI = $('<li />');
newLI.click(...);
newLI.mouseout(...);
$(document.body).append(newLI); // Incorrect
```